# Angular 2 sharing data from component to service and back to another component

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have component where I set the value of Boolean variable into the service, and another component where I have subscribed to the same service.

The problem is that I am not getting any updates on the Component 2 where I am subscribed.

If I put the subscribe method in the Component 1 ngOnInit everything works fine.

Thank you very much!

Sample

Component 1

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {SharedService} from '../shared/shared.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'welcome',
    templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./welcome.component.css'],
    providers: [SharedService],
})

export class WelcomeComponent {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

    contentClicked(){
        this.sharedService.setSaveBtnStatus(true);
    }
}
```

Component 2

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {SharedService} from '../shared/shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css'],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class NavigationComponent {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.sharedService.getSaveBtnStatus().subscribe(
        data => console.log(data),
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('finished')
      );
  }
}
```

Service

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
    private showSaveBtn = new Subject<boolean>();

    getSaveBtnStatus(){
        return this.showSaveBtn.asObservable();
    }

    setSaveBtnStatus(value: boolean){
        this.showSaveBtn.next(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `providers` in `@Component` like this

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css'],
  providers: [SharedService]  // <-- here
})
```

It means that each component will have its own instance of your service.

Move this to `AppModule.ts` inside of `@NgModule`, then the service will be the same across the module.

You can read when to inject in Component [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-root-component-or-module)